# Using Alias in a Select then using this when joining tables.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope someone can help.

I have used an alias as so..

```
select COALESCE(A1.Date, A2.Date, A3.Date, All.Date) as ADate,
.
.
.
) A2
on ADate.Date = A2.Date
```

It's giving me an error The multi-part identifier "ADate.Date" could not be bound.

Many thanks

Comment: `ADate` is a _column_ alias, but you are trying to use it in a join condition, as a _table_ alias.  Please post your full query.

Comment: Check out Logical Processing Order at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it as

```
select COALESCE(A1.Date, A2.Date, A3.Date, All.Date) as ADate,
.
.
.
) A2
on COALESCE(A1.Date, A2.Date, A3.Date, All.Date) = A2.Date
```